# Card.IO is not capturing the credit card holder name

Tags: ios, card.io

Is there any to capture the credit card holder's name in Card IO?

Following property only allow the manually enter the name

```
collectCardholderName = YES;
```

Comment: Got any solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: as far as I know this is not possible with card.io, it "just" reads card number and expiration date